# I keep getting a maximum message size quota for incominng messages (65536) has been exceeded even though I have set mine high

Tags: wcf, error-handling

I keep getting this error...

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

Even though I have my MaxReceivedMessageSize equal to 2147483647... Which is almost an order of magnitude greater than that first number.  What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you adjust MaxReceivedMessageSize on both the client-side and server-side?

Comment: ***UPDATE: Figured it out.***
I just checked. It was actually on the client side That I needed to change that setting. thanks for your help.

Comment: I just checked. On both the client and server side I have the value set to the maximum value?!?!?!? Let me double check.